# Post Request using RestKit

Tags: objective-c, restkit-0.20

I am new to RestKit and I am banging my head to post the Userdata on to the server

Here's the thing what I am doing is

#UserData.h
       @interface UserProfile : NSObject

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *secondName;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *userName;

@end
```

and

```
- (void)configureRestKit
{
    // initialize AFNetworking HTTPClient
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xx.xxx.xx/myApp"];
    AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

    // initialize RestKit
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];

    RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[UserData class]];
    [responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"firstName", @"secondName", @"userName"]];
    NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful); // Anything in 2xx
    RKResponseDescriptor *articleDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:statusCodes];

    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping]; // objectClass == NSMutableDictionary
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"firstName", @"secondName", @"userName"]];

    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[UserData class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodAny];

    RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xx.xxx.xx/myApp"]];
    [manager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [manager addResponseDescriptor:articleDescriptor];

    UserData *user = [UserData new];
    user.firstName = @"firstName";
    user.secondName = @"secondName";
    user.userName = @"userName";

    // POST to create
    // [manager postObject:user path:@"/registration" parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];

    [manager postObject:user path:@"/userdata/regis" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
       NSLog(@"User is registered: %@", mappingResult.array);

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error': %@", error);
    }];

}
```

I am getting error

```
 Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x1700f9e80 {NSUnderlyingError=0x17824e340 "The request timed out."
```

Not sure why?

Here's the restsApi detail 
BaseURL : http://xx.xxx.xx/myApp
Function name : /regis
controName: userdata
Params : UserData objUserData
returntype : userDetail obj

Comment: So does the path `http://xx.xxx.xx/myApp/userdata/regis` actually exist? What does the server log say?

Comment: @Wain : yes its exist ....where am I going wrong ? ?

Comment: Unclear, hopefully the server can tell you via logs. Or you have some network issue...